# Chrome background image issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I have three `div` tags for displaying header image.

- First `div` will have left aligned logo
- Third `div` will have right aligned logo
- And the center `div` should repeat a blank background image adjusting to the screen width.

I have given 100% width for the center `div` tag. It is working in IE, whereas in Chrome the center tag extends the screen width. The background image extends the screen width for the length of first and last `div` tag. For example if first and last image is 20% and I want the center `div` to adjust for 60% but in Chrome it is taking 140% 20 + 20 for first and last and 100% for the middle tag.

Need help!

Comment: Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue? (Edit your question, click on the icon that looks like a piece of paper with <> in it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your css is the issue here. Have a good look at this snippet. Works fine. :)

```css
.left {
  width: 9%;background-image:url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/skype.jpg");  background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top left;}
  .right {
    width: 9%;background-image:url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/email.jpg");  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top right;}
    .middle {
      width: 80%;background-image:url("http://placehold.it/400x400"); background-repeat:repeat-x; height:150px; background-size:contain;}
      header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 0!important, padding: 0!important;
      }
      .left,
      .right,
      .middle {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 150px;
      }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="middle">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
</header>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2v9a8js1/5/

Comment: This is working fine for screen resolution 1280*1024. If i re size the screen there is blank screen in the mid of images.

Comment: well my images  are very small you can replace them with bigger ones and you can adjust the widths

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2v9a8js1/6/

Comment: and you can put a background on the header

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2v9a8js1/7/

Comment: please put a tick beside my answer. a check mark will appear when you hover beside it. when you click it it will go green. Both you and I get points! :)